# Erro de permissão ao tentar acessar banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, zend

Peguei um projetinho já pronto pra estudar, só que está dando esse erro, recentemente migrei para o ubuntu e não sei o que fazer.

> Erro: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Comment: Esse erro pode ter tantos motivos... comece verificando se está usando a senha correta... onde esse projetinho armazena a configuração de conexão ao banco de dados?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Já enfrentei esse erro. Será que o root está configurado para usar uma senha mesmo? Pode testar essa hipotése digitando isso:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root
```

*Obs.:* não tem a opção `-p` para dar a senha

Comment: Mysql 5.7 se não me engano não aceita mais acesso direto via root que não seja uma aplicação terminal com aceso pelo "sudo", precisa-se criar um novo usuário. Veja essa resposta no site do Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/a/763359/689807 . Isso é só um acréscimo para quem está perdido e não consegue achar a resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Este erro ocorre devido ao host. Pode ser o host que ele escuta ou permissão.

Tente trocar `localhost` para `127.0.0.1`

Se não resolver tente dar permissão de acesso para o usuário root para localhost

Entre no console do mysql abrindo um terminal e execute

```
mysql -h localhost -u root
```

Se possuir senha execute assim

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Quando entrar execute o seguinte comando

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'localhost'
```

A parte depois do @ é o host que faz a conexão, então você deve dar permissão para todos os hosts que devem fazer a conexão. no host você pode especificar um dominio ou mesmo usar o curinga '%' para permitir acesso a qualquer host. Atenção para não deixar o acesso a qualquer host em servidores de produção, pois é uma falha muito grande de segurança.

Caso não resolva, verifique se a senha está correta.

Answer (score 3):

Esse problema sugere que provavelmente está acessando o MySQL sem especificar o usuário e está dando uma senha para um usuário que não é o root. Ao mudar de servidor, por algum motivo o usuário default passou a ser root, pelo que a senha deve estar errada.

Se é mesmo esse o caso, recomendo que sempre se conecte explicitamente ao banco de dados usando um usuário e senha em vez de assumir a conexão padrão.

Answer (score 3):

Esse erro aconteceu porque a senha que estava especificado no script, onde se faz a conexão com o banco de dados, era diferente da senha de root da minha máquina. Erro bobo por falta de atenção mas que fica de experiencia para ajudar os irmãos.

Comment: Você pode aceitar sua resposta então, se achar que essa é realmente a solução. Se estiver apenas comentando, é melhor apagar a resposta e deixar como comentário. Respostas devem responder a perguntar.