# PHP Database error

Tags: php, mysql

Fiz upload do meu site (usando o filezilla) utilizando o php/mysql. No localhost funciona perfeitamente mas no server externo não. 
Aparece o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    exit('Database error.');
}
?>
```

O que poderia estar faltando?

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro? Ou o resultado é uma tela em branco?

Comment: Obrigado, editei a minha questão

Comment: Você pode explicitar a linha em que há a declaração de conexão ao banco de dados? Pode também verificar se os dados de conexão estão apontando para as credenciais fornecidas pelo seu provedor de hospedagem?

Comment: Muda o local do banco, deve ta como localhost, quando você sobe a aplicação, tem mudar, e colocar o link externo do banco.

Comment: Pus em cima, e creio que já sei. Deve ter a ver com "mysql:host=localhost"? mas o que por em vez disso?

Comment: No lugar de `exit('database error')` deixe `print_r($e)`) isso vai dar a mensagem de erro.

Comment: No host externo é preciso dar acesso ao usuario root ou criar um certinho. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4668/erro-de-permissao-ao-tentar-acessar-banco-de-dados) tem uma pergunta parecida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mensagem idica que o acesso foi negado para o usuário `root` em `localhost`.

Isso siginifica que o seu host está correto, e você está conseguindo chegar lá no banco, porém ele não está reconhecendo como válido seu banco e/ou usuário e/ou senha.

Verifique junto ao provedor os dados corretos de acesso do MySQL e insira nos campos.