# Problema de permissão 'PDOException'

Tags: php, session, login

Estou obtendo um erro de permissão pra criar a sessão do [Huge Login](https://github.com/panique/huge):

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES)' in
> /var/www/html/myproject/application/core/DatabaseFactory.php on line 42
>
> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> /var/www/html/myproject/application/core/DatabaseFactory.php on line
> 42

Seguindo alguns respostas do SOen como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896264/fatal-error-pdoexception-sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied), já modifiquei as permissões das pastas da aplicação e da pasta `tmp` pra `-R 777`, alterei a senha do root, etc, mas nada não resolveu.

O arquivo `DatabaseFactory.php`:

```
<?php
class DatabaseFactory
{
    private static $factory;
    private $database;

    public static function getFactory()
    {
        if (!self::$factory) {
            self::$factory = new DatabaseFactory();
        }
        return self::$factory;
    }
    public function getConnection() {
        if (!$this->database) {
            $options = array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $this->database = new PDO(
                Config::get('DB_TYPE') . ':host=' . Config::get('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' .
                Config::get('DB_NAME') . ';port=' . Config::get('DB_PORT') . ';charset=' . Config::get('DB_CHARSET'),
                Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS'), $options
            );
        }
        return $this->database; // ->>> linha 42
    }
}
```

Os dados de configuração do BD:

```
'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',
'DB_HOST' => '127.0.0.1',
'DB_NAME' => 'huge',
'DB_USER' => 'root',
'DB_PASS' => 'password',
'DB_PORT' => '3306',
'DB_CHARSET' => 'utf8',
```

Os privilégios do BD `huge`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sistema:

> Servidor: Localhost via UNIX socket
> **Tipo de servidor: MySQL
>  Versão do servidor: 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1** - (Ubuntu)
>  Versão do protocolo: 10
>  Usuário: root@localhost
>  Charset do servidor: UTF-8 Unicode
> (utf8)

(na última linha apaguei o nome da minha maq. por segurança...)

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Tente mudar de `localhost` para `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti Na configuração de acesso ao BD (no framework) já estou usando `127.0.0.1` ( e no navegador tbm), mas no erro continua aparecendo root@localhost. Tem algum outro arquivo que preciso mudar isso?

Comment: Coloca a versão do seu mysql. O banco está na mesma maquina q vc esta trabalhando(ou seja o acesso não vem de uma maquina remota)?

Comment: Não sei como funciona no framework que você está usando, mas tente alterar diretamente a string de conexão para fazer um teste.

Comment: Entendi, o erro ao meu ver parece mais uma definição de acesso ao banco, você definiu corretamente esses dados em seu config? `Config::get('DB_USER')` e `Config::get('DB_PASS')`

Comment: Se está utilizando doctrine, experimente apagar o cache.

Comment: Da um echo nessa STRING de conexao porque o problema é ela com certeza. pois se voce coloca 127.0.0.1 e ele nao muda no erro... ele ta pegando string de conexao padrao!

Comment: @rray o banco está na mesma máquina sim. O mysql é o 5.5.44 (editei a pergunta com os dados do sistema)...

Comment: Dá um echo nisso:  `Config::get('DB_TYPE') . ':host=' . Config::get('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' .
                Config::get('DB_NAME') . ';port=' . Config::get('DB_PORT') . ';charset=' . Config::get('DB_CHARSET'),
                Config::get('DB_USER'), Config::get('DB_PASS')`; die(); e veja o que acontece.

Comment: @Daniloloko acho que me expressei mal. Ele não muda o erro... mesmo eu colocando 127.0.0.1, ele dá escreve no erro `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: Eu olhei o link do SO que vc sugeriu na pergunta, vc tentou resolver [assim](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4681/91) ?

Comment: @rray segui esta resposta agora, mas não resolveu... tava olhando as outras respostas (nice link btw), e tentando seguir [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4672/23400), recebi o erro `$ sudo mysql -h localhost -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Comment: Então, não sei se é o seu problema ... com as versões mais novas do mysql tive problema para criar uma senha para o root, dizia que o hash gerarado era muito curto ... se achar o link te mando. Tenta logar via linha de comando e mudar a senha do root. não esuqeça o `-p`

Comment: Ok @rray, vou tentar aqui. Valeu! PS: Um detalhe é que só com o huge login não acesso o db, quando quero gravar no banco sem usar o framework, (fazendo a conexão direto por uma página de formulário por exemplo) funciona normalmente...

Comment: Ah, descobri o que era. É que eu instalei em um diretório, e depois só copiei a pasta vendor no diretório que já tinha criado antes (achando que não precisava do conteúdo todo da instalação dentro do projeto), então ele tava indo buscar a senha no diretório da instalação. Daí mudei a senha lá e ficou de boas. ^^ Valeu a todos que tentaram ajudar!  Vou indicar essa pergunta como duplicata da que o @rray indicou... valeu mesmo. Abraços.